# Query Returns All Elements/Fields

Tags: list

I am trying to get the data that matches my query but for some reason it just ignores the query and returns all the fields.
My code is as follows. I am using Web services and the sharepoint server is 2003.

```
string queryString= "<In><FieldRef Name='Department' /><Values>";

string[] departments = txtDepartment.Text.Split(',');
for (int i = 0; i < departments.Length; i++)
{
    queryString += "<Value Type='Text'>"+departments[i]+"</Value>";
}
queryString += "</Values></In>";
query.InnerXml = queryString;
nodeListItems = mList.GetListItems(listName, guid, query, null, "5500", null, null);
```

Could you please advise me where am I going wrong. If I put  at the begging and end it throws soap exception.

Comment: string queryString= "<In><FieldRef Name='Department' /><Values>";
                               
                string[] departments = txtDepartment.Text.Split(',');
                for (int i = 0; i < departments.Length; i++)
                {
                    queryString += "<Value Type='Text'>"+departments[i]+"</Value>";
                }
                queryString += "</Values></In>";
                query.InnerXml = queryString;
    nodeListItems = mList.GetListItems(listName, guid, query, null, "5500", null, null);

Comment: Its the post that is not showing the complete code. I have pasted it.

Answer (score 1):

The `<In>` element isn't supported prior to SharePoint 2010. See other versions in the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625761%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

My guess is, that it was introduced in order to support querying for Managed Terms.

If the 2003 in the question is a typo then your issue may be missing the `<Query>`, `<Where>`, `</Where>` and `</Query>` elements

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the closing

```
</In>
```

to the queryString, but it doesn't look like you're adding the starting

```
<In><Values>
```